# Why is the Voltage Gain 54 dB instead of 50 as stated in the problem?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]
Here I'm trying to find the overall voltage gain. I did everything correctly, except out of nowhere, the gain in dB was 54dB, not 50dB. I don't know why. Here's the solution: [image]

And here's the figure (or problem statement)

[image]

Can someone explain why?

Comment: Just looks like a typo. The professors who write textbooks and the grad students who proofread the problem sets at 3 AM are not infallible.

Answer (score 2):

could be a typo... quick analysis....

- Voltage gain, Av remains ~50dB or 49.7 @16Ω assumes Av=no load

  - (negligible load loss -0.3dB @16Ω)
- Current gain, Ai=Av*Rin/Rout or in log format Av(dB)+Ar(dB)

  - where  Rin/Rout= 1M/{1kΩ:16Ω}  = {1000:62,500} = {60dB:96dB}
- Power gain,   Ap(dB)=Ai(dB) + Av(dB) = {50+60;49.7+96} for {1kΩ:16Ω}